# Use Batch file to add headers to CSV

Tags: batch-file

I have a CSV file that has data that I need to add headers to. I want it to look like this

```
group  id  firstname   lastname   homephone
acme   1      joe         moe     555555555
```

Currently it looks like this

```
acme   1      joe         moe     5555555555
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend: take Excel please.

Comment: Well I like the advice. I can do this all day long in excel. I need to automate it. Hence why I asked for a batch file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@echo off    
echo group  id  firstname   lastname   homephone > new.csv
type old.csv >> new.csv
```

Type command does not work good with unicode symbols , but this should be ok if your file contains only ascii-ies.

Comment: It added the headers by adds all those words to the first coulmn

Comment: npocmaka-- I had to add group,id,...... But Thank you for getting me thinking in the right direction.

Comment: I must be missing something...does the type command work different on mac? I am getting a file not found error when I type that command even though I am in the directory and can see the file if I type "ls"

Comment: @Praxiteles - Mac's have completely different shell - bash. Try to search for the same thing but instead of batch use `bash`

Comment: @npocmaka i also have the same kind of work, getting all the values in the first column. how did you separate to other columns. for example :group in colA , Id in colB ,.. please help me ..

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment yet. but wanted to post what worked for me. I used npocmaka's answer and added double quotes and commas, which is what I needed. I also needed to replace the existing file with the one with headings, so I added a delete and rename. Thanks!

```
@echo off    
echo "Salesman Code","Salesman Name","Description","Manager Code","Region","Reg SM#","Reg SM Long" > CO_REPNEW.CSV
type CO_REP.CSV >> CO_REPNEW.CSV
del CO_REP.CSV
ren CO_REPNEW.CSV CO_REP.CSV
```