# SQL Server: copy headers after bat to extract data

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, bcp

I have many files that are extracted into `.txt` with a batch file. But they don't have the headers. I've read that a possible solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794894/use-batch-file-to-add-headers-to-csv) that is to add to a `.txt` with the headers the exported rows.

With this:

```
echo. >> titles.txt
type data.txt >> titles.txt
```

This takes a lot of time and is not efficient, since it is adding the big file to the file with the text.

Another possible solution is to add to the SQL query the titles hardcoded, but this will change the type of the columns (is they are numeric they will be changed to varchar).

Is there a way to insert in the first row of the data txt the headers and not doing vice-versa?

Comment: Please explain to me how adding to the SQL query the column headers changes the column type?  Thank you.

Comment: @tale852150, as I said "Is they are numeric they will be changed to varchar"

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but as far as I am informed (and as far as I know from earlier experiments in doing as described): No, it is not possible! The mentioned Tasks are acting on the file sequentially. You can either open a file for reading, writing or appending. If you open the titles.txt file for writing, it is overwritten - and with this empty. If you open it for appending, it can only append to the end of the file - so you can only write the data after the Header... the only way it might work - but which is pretty nasty - is to append the title to the end of the file and during later processing (e.g. xls or whatever) Resort the rows and put the last one to the beginning. But as mentioned: nasty and not really the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of files to process is a bigger problem than any individual file size, switching from [bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) to [sqlcmd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) might help.